# Want better desktop widget currency converter

Tags: widgets

Ubuntu version: 18.04 LTS

I use this a lot: https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+to+eur

It also includes, gbp to eur , gbp to usd and vice verca. So basically I need a converter with those 3 main pairs, if AUD is included would be good too.

The most important thing is that it would allow me to insert my own source for the rates, which I would like to use this google one.

Any not-bloated currency converter desktop widgets out there? :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a widget, but you may use the `gnome-calculator` Financial mode:

[image: gnome-calculator]

Rates are updated daily and saved in `~/.cache/gnome-calculator/eurofxref-daily.xml` or `~/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gnome-calculator/eurofxref-daily.xml` for the snap version of `gnome-calculator`.

[See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409008/currency-conversion-calculator-in-debian).

Comment: What do I do to keep this being updated? This file was last modified in 2018 on my system.

Comment: Turns out I was using the `snap` version. This doesn't even *have* a financial mode. I `snap remove`d it and `apt install`ed the `deb` version, but nothing has changed. It looks the same. What version are you running? Mine is 3.34.1.

Comment: Apologies, it does have a financial mode. It's just not at the place I would expect it: in the top bar, what looks like the window title is actually a drop-down selector. And with the subsequent `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` there came a new version of `eurofxref-daily.xml`. Thanks!

Comment: But it is not a widget, its an application which I would have to open every time I need it. 

Is there a widget that would constantly sit on my desktop where I could just enter the amount in X currency and it would instantly print me the amount in Y currency?

Comment: You're right, I don't know ...